# Initializing Camera with a button results in blank screen, initializing in onCreate works fine

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I am working on an app that needs to control the camera, but I've run into an issue when I try to initialize it.

If I call the function `SafeOpenCamera()` inside `onCreate()` everything works fine and I can see the camera preview. However if I try to call it when I press a button, the area where the preview should be goes blank.

In both cases "Camera started" gets logged, and I get no exceptions.

I've tried to figure this out for a few days but I can't find the cause.
I need to activate it with a button so the user can choose which camera to use and, hopefully, swap them while the app is running.

Main Activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private View mCameraView;
    private Button ulButton;
    private int current_camera=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ulButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.ul_button);
        ulButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // If I try to start the camera with the button, the preview area goeas blank
                boolean opened = safeOpenCamera((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview_layout), current_camera);
                if (opened == false) {
                    Log.d("Camera", "Error, Camera failed to open");
                } else {
                    Log.d("Camera", "Camera started");
                }
            }
        });

        // If I place the code for opening the camera here, it works fine: //        
        /*boolean opened = safeOpenCamera((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview_layout), current_camera);
        if (opened == false) {
            Log.d("Camera", "Error, Camera failed to open");
        } else {
            Log.d("Camera", "Camera started");
        }*/

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private boolean safeOpenCamera(View view, int camera_id){
        Log.d("SafeOpenCamera","starting method");
        boolean qOpened=false;
        releaseCameraAndPreview();
        Log.d("SafeOpenCamera", "camera id " + camera_id);
        mCamera=getCameraInstance(camera_id);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCameraView=view;
        qOpened=(mCamera!=null);
        if(qOpened==true) {
            Log.d("SafeOpenCamera","qOpened true");
            mPreview = new CameraPreview(getBaseContext(), mCamera,mCameraView);
            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview_layout);
            preview.addView(mPreview);
            mPreview.startCameraPreview();
            //addItemsOnSpinner2(mPreview.getSizes());

        }
        return qOpened;
    }
    public Camera getCameraInstance(int camera_id){
        Camera c=null;
        try{
            c = Camera.open(camera_id);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return c;
    }
    private void releaseCameraAndPreview(){
        if(mCamera!=null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
        //if(mPreview!=null){
        //mPreview.destroyDrawingCache();

        //}
    }
}
```

Preview class:

```
    public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Context mContext;
    private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;
    private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedSizes;
    private List<String> mSupportedFlashModes;
    private View mCameraView;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera, View cameraView){
        super(context);

        mCameraView=cameraView;
        mContext=context;
        setCamera(camera);

        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void startCameraPreview(){
        try{
            Log.d("Terminal preview","Try set preview");
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            Log.d("Terminal preview", "Try start preview");
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Terminal preview","exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<Camera.Size> getSizes(){
        return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes();
    }

    private void setCamera(Camera camera){
        Log.d("Terminal preview","set camera");
        mCamera=camera;
        mSupportedPreviewSizes=mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        mSupportedSizes=mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes();
        mSupportedFlashModes=mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedFlashModes();

        Camera.Parameters parameters=mCamera.getParameters();
        Log.d("Terminal preview","set rotation");
        parameters.setRotation(90);

        if(mSupportedFlashModes!=null && mSupportedFlashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO)){
            Log.d("Terminal preview","set flash mode");
            parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);

        }
        Log.d("Terminal preview","set params");
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        Log.d("Terminal preview", "requesting layout...");
        requestLayout();
    }



    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h){
        Log.d("Terminal preview", "Surface changed");
        if (mHolder.getSurface()==null){
            Log.d("Terminal preview","mHolder null, return");
            return;
        }
        try{
            Log.d("Terminal preview","Try stop preview");
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("Terminal", "surfaceChanged exception stopPreview");}

        try{
            Camera.Parameters parameters=mCamera.getParameters();

            if (mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedFocusModes().contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
                Log.d("Terminal preview", "set focus mode");
                parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            }

            if(mPreviewSize!=null){
                Camera.Size previewSize=mPreviewSize;
                parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
            }


            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("Terminal","surfaceChanged exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try{
            Log.d("Terminal preview", "try surfaceCreated");
            if(mCamera==null){Log.d("Terminal","mCamera es null");}
            if(holder==null){Log.d("Terminal","holder es null");}
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview(); //
        }catch (IOException e   ){
            Log.d("Terminal preview", "exception surfaceCreated");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d("Terminal preview", "surface destroyed");
        if (mCamera!=null){
            try{
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera=null;
            }catch (Exception e){Log.d("Terminal preview", "exception surface destroyed");}
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        Log.d("Terminal preview", "onMeassure");
        final int width=resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(),widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height=resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes!=null){
            mPreviewSize=getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes,width,height);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        Log.d("Terminal preview", "onLayout");
        if (changed) {

            final int width=right-left;
            final int height=top-bottom;
            int previewWidth=width;
            int previewHeight=height;

            if(mPreviewSize!=null){
                Display display=((WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

                switch (display.getRotation()){
                    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                        previewWidth=mPreviewSize.height;
                        previewHeight=mPreviewSize.width;
                        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                        previewWidth=mPreviewSize.width;
                        previewHeight=mPreviewSize.height;
                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                        previewWidth=mPreviewSize.height;
                        previewHeight=mPreviewSize.width;
                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                        previewWidth=mPreviewSize.width;
                        previewHeight=mPreviewSize.height;
                        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
                        break;
                }
            }
            Log.d("Terminal","t,b,l,r: "+top+" "+bottom+" "+left+" "+right);
            Log.d("Terminal","w: "+width);
            Log.d("Terminal","h: "+height);

            Log.d("Terminal","pw: "+previewWidth);
            Log.d("Terminal","ph: "+previewHeight);

            final int scaledChildHeight=previewHeight*width/previewWidth;

            Log.d("Terminal","h-sh: "+(height-scaledChildHeight));

            mCameraView.layout(0, height - scaledChildHeight, width, height);

        }
    }


    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int width, int height){
        Log.d("Terminal preview", "getOptimalPreviewSize");
        Camera.Size optimalSize=null;
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE=0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double)height/width;

        for(Camera.Size size: sizes){
            if(size.height!=width) continue;
            double ratio=(double)size.width/size.height;
            if(ratio<=targetRatio+ASPECT_TOLERANCE && ratio >targetRatio-ASPECT_TOLERANCE){
                optimalSize=size;
            }
        }
        if(optimalSize==null){

        }
        return optimalSize;
    }


}
```

This is the log that I get when the camera is initialized in onCreate() (the one that works)

```
/SafeOpenCamera﹕ starting method
/SafeOpenCamera﹕ camera id 1
/dalvikvm﹕ Note: class Lcom/lge/mdm/manager/ILGMDMDevicePolicyManager$Stub; has 235 unimplemented (abstract) methods
/SafeOpenCamera﹕ qOpened true
/Terminal preview﹕ set camera
/Terminal preview﹕ set rotation
/Terminal preview﹕ set params
/Terminal preview﹕ requesting layout...
/Terminal preview﹕ Try set preview
/Camera﹕ app passed NULL surface
/Terminal preview﹕ Try start preview
/Camera﹕ Camera started
/Terminal preview﹕ onMeassure
/Terminal preview﹕ getOptimalPreviewSize
/Terminal preview﹕ onMeassure
/Terminal preview﹕ getOptimalPreviewSize
/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
/Terminal preview﹕ onLayout
/Terminal﹕ t,b,l,r: 0 300 0 492
/Terminal﹕ w: 492
/Terminal﹕ h: -300
/Terminal﹕ pw: 492
/Terminal﹕ ph: -300
/Terminal﹕ h-sh: 0
/Terminal preview﹕ onLayout
/Terminal preview﹕ try surfaceCreated
/Terminal preview﹕ Surface changed
/Terminal preview﹕ Try stop preview
/Terminal preview﹕ onMeassure
/Terminal preview﹕ getOptimalPreviewSize
/Terminal preview﹕ onMeassure
/Terminal preview﹕ getOptimalPreviewSize
/Terminal preview﹕ onLayout
```

Here's the log I get when I try to initialize it with the button (the one that doesn't work)

```
/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewRoot  TouchDown(Absolute) DOWN (105 , 202)
/SafeOpenCamera﹕ starting method
/SafeOpenCamera﹕ camera id 1
/dalvikvm﹕ Note: class Lcom/lge/mdm/manager/ILGMDMDevicePolicyManager$Stub; has 235 unimplemented (abstract) methods
/SafeOpenCamera﹕ qOpened true
/Terminal preview﹕ set camera
/Terminal preview﹕ set rotation
/Terminal preview﹕ set params
/Terminal preview﹕ requesting layout...
/Terminal preview﹕ Try set preview
/Camera﹕ app passed NULL surface
/Terminal preview﹕ Try start preview
/Camera﹕ Camera started
/Terminal preview﹕ onMeassure
/Terminal preview﹕ getOptimalPreviewSize
/Terminal preview﹕ onMeassure
/Terminal preview﹕ getOptimalPreviewSize
/Terminal preview﹕ onLayout
/Terminal﹕ t,b,l,r: 0 300 0 492
/Terminal﹕ w: 492
/Terminal﹕ h: -300
/Terminal﹕ pw: 492
/Terminal﹕ ph: -300
/Terminal﹕ h-sh: 0
/Terminal preview﹕ onLayout
/Terminal preview﹕ try surfaceCreated
/Terminal preview﹕ Surface changed
/Terminal preview﹕ Try stop preview
```

The only differences between the logs seem to be that when the preview is successfuly drawn onMeassure() gets called, and the loading of the libraries: libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so, libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so and libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so, and I don't know whether they are related to the camera or not.

In the layout I've set the preview area to have a colored background, which turns to white when I try to initialize the preview with the button, addView() is the function that's not working properly.

The source code can be found here in case someone has the time to check it:
[dropbox](https://db.tt/UIWRkgu1)

Comment: You don't need `mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);`. Thats useless now. Ill check to see what could be causing your problem though

Comment: Are you getting logs for the preview starting?

Comment: Can you post a log output for when you use the button, and for when you just add it?

Comment: Sorry, I forgaot about adding the logs, there they are.

Comment: Can you post just your logs? Thats hard to read

Comment: I'm sorryI'm not sure I understand what you mean. Just the logs I print with Log.d() ?

Comment: The way you start your preview in safeOpenCamera...you aren't necessarily waiting for the surface holder to be created. There is a callback, `surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)` that gets called. Can you try making sure you `startPreview()` in there?

Comment: There is a call to    mCamera.startPreview(); inside surfaceCreated, I tried removing the mPreview.startCameraPreview(); e safeOpenCamera() and everything is still the same.

Something that I just noticed is that after I press the button the whole screen goes black for a fraction of second.

Comment: On every startPreviewCall can you do a 1 second delay. Wait a second, then call it on the main thread. Do that for EVERY startPreviewCall and tell me if it works after that

Comment: I used new CountDownTimer(1000, 100) beforeevery call to startPreview() and it still isn't working with the button. During that second I see a black rectangle for the onCreate initialization (which never shows with the button), so what's failing must be prior to startPreview(). I'll keep trying to log as much info as I can to see what differsbetween the two scenarios.     

It seems to me that the FrameLayout where I place the preview is getting hidden, moved, or removed, but I can't find why. I don't see what changes in the process that could result in said frame disappearing.

Comment: The problem is definitely in frameLayoutaddView(mPreview), when it is called the frameLayout disappears,I don't know why, I've tried to call requestLayout() afterwards to no avail, and I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Can you put your project up on Github or zip it and post it?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to check this. I've added a link to the code, sorry for the delay, I was trying to upload it to gitHub but in the end I didn't find a way. https://db.tt/UIWRkgu1

Comment: Its not connecting to the camera service.

Comment: Very weird...Im not sure yet...It looks like some sort of layout issue

Comment: Ok Good news. I found the source of the problem. Its inside your onLayout override. If you comment that out, you'll see its working fine. So there is some bug in there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're right. Not the preview gets drawn.I got this from a tutorial/example, and I never thought of deleting that cause I though it was required for this to work.

Comment: I posted an answer below so we can mark this answer complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through your code. The problem is on the onLayout call.

If you ignore the changed param (always call your code), you get a stack overflow because there is an infinite amount of layout calls. The problem is in the logic of how you are using onLayout. I can't dive into it further right now (took long enough as it is to get here haha). But removing this function causes both the button and non button scenario to work.

So I would look at where you are calling change in layout code and change the logic of how you want to size your layout. But as for the problem posted here, its the code below. Remove this function and your code will run. That should get you going again!
(Offending code is below)

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    if (changed) {

        final int width=right-left;
        final int height=top-bottom;
        int previewWidth=width;
        int previewHeight=height;

        if(mPreviewSize!=null){

            Display display=((WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

            switch (display.getRotation()){
                case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                    previewWidth=mPreviewSize.height;
                    previewHeight=mPreviewSize.width;
                    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                    previewWidth=mPreviewSize.width;
                    previewHeight=mPreviewSize.height;
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                    previewWidth=mPreviewSize.height;
                    previewHeight=mPreviewSize.width;
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                    previewWidth=mPreviewSize.width;
                    previewHeight=mPreviewSize.height;
                    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
                    break;
            }
        }

        final int scaledChildHeight=previewHeight*width/previewWidth;

        mCameraView.layout(0, height - scaledChildHeight, width, height);

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your exact problem is but I've had similar issue. Instead of inflating the View where your `SurfaceView` is, you can insert an empty one with zero width and height in your main layout. That way, it will be way faster. Try inserting that in your main XML Layout, `activity_main`

```
<SurfaceView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="0dp" />
```